# Logic error when show a winform if the check change event of check edit control occur?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have two winforms. I call parent and child forms. On parent form I have a check edit control. I want to show child form when it checked (m_chkEdit.checked = true)
Both the check and uncheck status of it are store in my registry. When parent form loaded, the status of check edit control would update it's status before.

Ok, parent form has two methods. OnLoad method loads and updates the status of m_chkEdit from registry. And m_chkEdit_CheckedChanged event method calls child form when I check it (m_chkEdit.Checked = true).

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);            

    RegistryData.ReadCheckEditStatus = m_chkEdit.Checked ? RegistryData.EnumCheckEdit.ReadCheckEditYes : RegistryData.EnumCheckEdit.ReadCheckEditNo;           
}

private void m_chkEdit_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (m_chkEdit.Checked)
    {
        ChildForm form = new ChildForm ();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Here is my problem: if the status of check edit control is checked previously, child form will show when parent form which is loaded. I just only want child form show when I check the checkEdit control.

I wonder that checkEdit has another event which could solve the problem?

Could you give me some advices?
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to temporarily unsubscribe from the `CheckedChanged` event:

```
m_chkEdit.CheckedChanged -= m_chkEdit_CheckedChanged;
m_chkEdit.Checked = ...; // <-- Restore checked status from registry here
m_chkEdit.CheckedChanged += m_chkEdit_CheckedChanged;
```

Comment: I would not go this way. Using flags is better pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some flag. This flag would be set to false in parent constructor and to true in OnShown event. In your m_chkEdit_CheckedChanged you would check this flag and open the child window only when flat is true. Thus you can set m_chkEdit in Load event.

Or second solution
Just register m_chkEdit_CheckedChanged after checkbox is set to proper value

Comment: The second solution of your solved it, but i prefer dmitry's. Thanks you so much!